# authorize aws security group using python boto3 with description for each ingress

Tags: python, boto3, aws-security-group

I am preparing a script to update security group with myip and static string when ever i am running with different network connection .

```
sg.authorize_ingress(DryRun=False,IpPermissions=[{'IpProtocol': 'tcp','FromPort': 22,'ToPort': 22,'IpRanges': [{'CidrIp': 192.168.2.3/32}]}])
```

above authorize is working fine but if i add

```
sg.authorize_ingress(DryRun=False,IpPermissions=[{'IpProtocol': 'tcp','FromPort': 22,'ToPort': 22,'IpRanges': [{'CidrIp': 192.168.2.3/32,'Description': 'string'}]}])
```

As per the syntax if i apply description part it throws an error msg . whether it is possible to update each and every entry with description.

syntax:

```
'IpRanges': [
                {
                    'CidrIp': 'string',
                    'Description': 'string'
                }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
import boto3

aws_access_key_id = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'

aws_secret_access_key = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'

ec2 = boto3.resource('ec2', region_name='region_name', aws_access_key_id=aws_access_key_id, aws_secret_access_key=aws_secret_access_key)

sg = "security group id"

security_group = ec2.SecurityGroup(sg)

add_ip = security_group.authorize_ingress(GroupId=sg,IpPermissions=[ {'IpProtocol': 'tcp','FromPort': 80,'ToPort': 80,'IpRanges':[{'CidrIp': '127.5.5.5/32', 'Description' : 'description'}]}])
```

Please try with above mentioned code . 
Because it's working fine for me . Hope it will work for you also .

Comment: I tried your solution but it doesn't seems to work for me: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58728964/setting-the-description-and-ipv6-using-authorize-security-group-ingress-of-aws-s

Comment: Which one? The one I asked?

Answer (score 1):

I do it using the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/):

```
IP=`curl -s http://whatismyip.akamai.com/`
aws ec2 authorize-security-group-ingress --group-name "Foo-SG" --protocol tcp --port 22   --cidr $IP/32 --output text
aws ec2 authorize-security-group-ingress --group-name "Foo-SG" --protocol tcp --port 3389 --cidr $IP/32 --output text
```

However, I haven't tried it with the `Description` parameter.

See: [authorize-security-group-ingress — AWS CLI Command Reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/authorize-security-group-ingress.html)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a general approach I use for boto3 to create ec2s and ssh in.

```
# Configure so you can SSH
ec2Client.modify_vpc_attribute( VpcId = vpc.id , EnableDnsSupport = { 'Value': DNS_SUPPORT })
ec2Client.modify_vpc_attribute( VpcId = vpc.id , EnableDnsHostnames = { 'Value': DNS_HOSTNAMES })

# Create a security group and allow SSH inbound rule through the VPC
securitygroup = ec2.create_security_group(
    GroupName=SG_GROUP_NAME,
    Description=SG_DESC,
    VpcId=vpc.id
)

securitygroup.authorize_ingress(
    IpPermissions=[
        {'IpProtocol': SG_IP_PROTOCOL,
         'FromPort': SG_FROM_PORT,
         'ToPort': SG_TO_PORT,
         'IpRanges': [{'CidrIp': SG_IP}]}
    ]
)
```

This is for ssh so:

```
SG_IP_PROTOCOL = 'tcp'
   SG_FROM_PORT = 22
   SG_TO_PORT = 22
   SG_IP = 'XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX/32' # your specified IP address
```

where

```
    ec2Client = boto3.client('ec2', region_name=aws_region)
```

[AWS Boto3 Documentation](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/ec2-example-security-group.html)